# CodeIgniter - Nothing is shown in the view

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I don’t know what the problem is. I have an ajax which sends username to the controller:

```
function my_profile(username){

    $.ajax({

       url: "member/my_profile",
       type: "get",
       data: "username="+username,
       success: function(){
           window.location.href = 'member/my_profile';
       }
    });
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
function my_profile(){


    $username = $this->input->get('username');
    $data['username'] = $username;
    $this->load->view('my_profile' , $data);
}
```

I have already echo the $username to test that it can alert(msg) from the ajax. It works just find. Problem is nothing is shown in my view:

```
    <h1>My Profile</h1>

<?php

echo $username;
?>
```

I don’t know why. I tried initialized `$data['username'] = 'adam'`  and this works.

Comment: What is the full URL of the page you're trying to view? Where is the ajax called from? What do you want to happen?

Comment: call `die();` after this `$this->load->view()`;

Comment: Why are you doing `window.location.href = 'member/my_profile';` after the AJAX call?  Why do an AJAX call if you're just gonna redirect there anyway?  That makes no sense.  Plus your redirect doesn't have the `username` parameter.

Comment: I actually wanted my middle content to change after the button my profile is click. Wanted to test whether the data is successfully get before I use ajax to change content. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `window.location.href = 'member/my_profile';`.  This will redirect you to the profile page *without* any `username` value.

You probably want to do:

```
 window.location.href = 'member/my_profile?username='+username;
```

Though, I still don't understand why you have that AJAX call there.  Couldn't you just do:

```
function my_profile(username){
     window.location.href = 'member/my_profile?username='+username;
}
```

Your AJAX call is loading the page then discarding the contents, I don't think you need it here.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling this is the problem.

Comment: what is the best way to hide the username? Does using ajax with get hide the username? Or must it be post? Because I understand that it would get pass to my controller, so maybe get or post makes no difference?

Comment: @JianShort: Why do you want to "hide" the username?  What are you trying to do?  I guess you could try storing the username in the session, that way it wouldn't need to be in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
   url: "member/my_profile",
   type: "get",
   data: "username="+username,
   success: function(){
       window.location.href = 'member/my_profile';
   }
});
```

Should be :

```
$.ajax({
   url: "member/my_profile?username=" + username,
   type: "get",
   success: function(){
       window.location.href = 'member/my_profile';
   }
});
```

Comment: Both are valid.  You can use the `data` option for `GET` requests.

Comment: @RocketHazmat , Nitish Kumar what is the best way to hide the username? Does using ajax with get hide the username? Or must it be post? Because I understand that it would get pass to my controller, so maybe get or post makes no difference? –